# Swift JSON parsing and printing a specified value from an array

Tags: ios, json, swift, xcode, swift3

Hi I'm trying to get data from a certain JSON API. I can gat a snapshot of all values from the API, which is shown below. But I can't manage to put a specifiek row in a variable. This is the JSON form which I get. I want to print the "Description" value.Can someone help me with this?
[image: The API result which I get]

And Hier is my code:

```
func apiRequest() {
    let config = URLSessionConfiguration.default
    let username = "F44C3FC2-91AF-5FB2-8B3F-70397C0D447D"
    let password = "G23@rE9t1#"
    let loginString = String(format: "%@:%@", username, password)
    let userPasswordData = loginString.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)
    let base64EncodedCredential = userPasswordData?.base64EncodedString()
    let authString = "Basic " + (base64EncodedCredential)!

    print(authString)
    config.httpAdditionalHeaders = ["Authorization" : authString]
    let session = URLSession(configuration: config)

    var running = false
    let url = NSURL(string: "https://start.jamespro.nl/v4/api/json/projects/?limit=10")

    let task = session.dataTask(with: url! as URL) {
        ( data, response, error) in
        if let taskHeader = response as? HTTPURLResponse {
            print(taskHeader.statusCode)
        }
        if error != nil {
            print("There is an error!!!")
            print(error)
        } else {
            if let content = data {
                do {
                    let array = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: content, options: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.mutableContainers) as AnyObject
                    print(array)

                    if let items = array["items"] {
                         if let description = items["Description"] as? [[String:Any]]{
                            print(description as Any)
                         }
                    }
                }
                catch {
                    print("Error: Could not get any data")
                }
            }
        }
        running = false
    }


    running = true
    task.resume()

    while running {
        print("waiting...")
        sleep(1)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all the `array` is **not** an array and not `AnyObject`, it's a dictionary which is `[String:Any]` in Swift 3.

```
let dictionary = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: content) as! [String:Any]
print(dictionary)
```

I don't know why all tutorials suggest `.mutableContainers` as option. That might be useful in Objective-C but is completely meaningless in Swift. Omit the parameter.

The object for key `items`is an array of dictionaries (again, the unspecified JSON type in Swift 3 is `Any)`. Use a repeat loop to get all `description` values and you have to downcast all values of a dictionary from `Any` to the expected type.

```
if let items = dictionary["items"] as? [[String:Any]] {
   for item in items {
       if let description = item["Description"] as? String {
          print(description)
       }
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanx a lot ! Nou I get it. You really helped me out !

Answer (score 0):

Looks like items is an array that needs to be looped through.  Here is some sample code, but I want to warn you that this code is not tested for your data.

```
if let items = array["items"] as? [[String: AnyObject]] {
    for item in items {
        if let description = item["Description"] as? String{
            print("Description: \(description)")
        }
    }
}
```

This code above, or some variation of it, should get you on the right track.

Answer (score 0):

use the SwiftyJSON and it would be as easy as `json["items"][i].arrayValue` as return and array with items Values or `json["items"][i]["description"].stringValue` to get a string from a row